# ThinkPad T440 keyboard not listed in LXQT settings Keyboard and Mouse

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, thinkpad, lxqt

I'm in 22.04.1, with Lubuntu, on a Lenovo ThinkPad t440.
I want to be able to switch between English and French keyboard settings.
I watched several videos on how to enter french characters, but nothing works for me, and I've read suggestions that one needs to have the correct keyboard selected in the first place;  but in LXQT settings -> keyboard and mouse -> keyboard layout, there's probably a hundred keyboard types listed, but there's no mention of any Lenovo.  Anybody here knows where I should start?

Comment: This maybe helpful https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/1411#issuecomment-396040034  (or that thread; Sorry I'm a *dumb aussie* & only barely speak english so haven't explored beyond defaults)  Also check you've applied all security fixes and upgrades; https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/02/24/ubuntu-22-04-2-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 22.04.2 but installed systems upgraded to 22.04.2 before that date!

Comment: If you haven't figured out at all how to use an English and French layout and switch between them, changing keyboard model won't make a difference. Just accept the default to start with, and focus on the LXQt documentation on how to add a new layout and layout switching.

Comment: Owning different Thinkpads, but not an T440 (t530 current), I never selected a specific keyboard for my model (just german keybindings). While I often use an external keyboard, I never have to adjust the driver while switching - in fact I can switch from character to character. If you need to chose a certain entry, since you abandoned the default entry and there is no "Default", look out for "Generic 105 keys" or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Mouse & Keyboard → Keyboard layout → add and choose french, the keyboard model isn't important as far as your keys work all.

at the bottom in this section there are the keys to choose

The panel has a plugin for displaying/switching between layouts.